# bash - using recursion - counting the executable files in dir

Tags: bash, shell, recursion

i am not looking for some high level ans, with just one line, i am trying to make a script that will work and to make it work with recursion and to understand it :)

I am trying to learn bash scripting, and geting into some problems:

I am trying to count the number of executable files in a dir and in its sub dirs

this it what i was thinking about

file name countFiles:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter = 0
for FILE in ($1/*)  /// going over all the files in the input path
do
 if (-d $FILE); then        /// checking if dir
  ./countFiles $FILE  /// calling the script again with ned path
  counter= $($counter + $0) /// addint to the counter the number of exe files from FILE
 fi
 if (-f $FILE); then /// checking if file
  if (-x $FILE); then /// checking id exe file
   counter = $counter + 1 // adding counter by 1
  fi
 fi
done
exit($counter) // return the number for exe files
```

Comment: This is not Bash! Now, wouldn't this do? `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for i; do [ -x "$i" ] && printf 1; done' _ {} \; | wc -c`

Comment: yes, its working, but im trying to make a script that will be easy for me to understand and to make similar scripts

Comment: Er...why not `find . -type f -executable | wc -l`?

Comment: @Wintermute: because this fails in the (arguably unlikely) case where a filename contains a newline: `touch $'a\nb'; chmod +x $'a\nb'; find . -type f -executable | wc -l`. Also `-executable` is not POSIX (I guess it's only available in GNU `find`). Apart from this, your command is fine.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yeah, okay. I guess the shell spawning just rubs me the wrong way. Perhaps `find . -type f -exec test -x '{}' \; -printf 1 | wc -c`? `-exec` *is* just another filter, after all.

Comment: @Wintermute looks good! I just realized that I made a typo in my first comment: I meant to use `-exec` with `+`: `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for i; do [ -x "$i" ] && printf 1; done' _ {} + | wc -c`, so that we're not spawning too many processes (and this might be slightly more efficient than spawning one `test` for each file). (Remark: `printf` is not POSIX.)

Comment: Isn't this the same script you posted a few hours ago? You deleted that question when I pointed out that you were trying to use `csh` syntax in a `bash` script. You said you were going to go back to your books and learn correct syntax. Why did you post the same question over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use recursion (which is a bad idea in Bash): first, don't call your script recursively. Instead, call a function recursively. This will be more efficient (no forking overhead). Trying to fix your syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

count_x_files() {
   # Counts number of executable (by user, regular and non-hidden) files
   # in directory given in first argument
   # Return value in variable count_x_files_ret
   # This is a recursive function and will fail miserably if there are
   # too deeply nested directories
   count_x_files_ret=0
   local file counter=0
   for file in "$1"/*; do
      if [[ -d $file ]]; then
         count_x_files "$file"
         ((counter+=count_x_files_ret))
      elif [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -x $file ]]; then
         ((++counter))
      fi
   done
   count_x_files_ret=$counter
}

count_x_files "$1"
echo "$count_x_files_ret"
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explained all the changes you made to fix his syntax errors. Just posting a correct script doesn't help someone understand all the differences between `csh` and `bash` syntax.

Comment: @Barmar: was waiting for OP to ask questions about specific points. Explaining _all_ the differences seems like a huge task! I guess OP can see a few important things by comparing his post and my answer. Feel free to edit my post if you can think of very important stuff to be added!

Comment: You're not just writing for the OP, you're writing an answer for anyone who reads this question in the future.

Comment: @Barmar: true. Now, you're making me feel bad `:(`. Though, the task of explaining stuff seems too big for the little reward it'll bring. This question will not have a large number of views, and I don't feel it's necessary to augment my answer. If in the future I see that it is viewed by a lot a people, or if I get too many downvotes for the low quality of my answer, I might consider adding some explanations.

Comment: its really self explained, i just read int like 20 times, some logic and its all understandable :)